# Remote desktop apps for OS X Mavericks 10.9

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I have tried CoRD, Microsoft Remote Desktop and RDC but all three are not compatible with Mavericks 10.9

Can someone recommend how I can connect to my Windows 7 computer from my mac?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Home? Professional?

Comment: @Rob I believe it's most likely professional at work (I'm a new starter), didn't check tbh. I'm on a Mac at home right now, wanting to connect to my Windows pc at work

Comment: Okay, taking this info in mind. Port 3389 (Windows Remote Desktop) is probably blocked in your work environment.

Comment: @Rob I don't think it should be, they gave me a vpn to connect to and recommended I use one of the recommended apps to login

Comment: Microsoft Remote Desktop is compatible: http://roaringapps.com/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-connection

Comment: Excuse me, you didn't explain about VPN in your question. Please add more details to your question, because that's pretty relevant.

Comment: Apologies. I'm connected to a VPN (PPTP) which I've configured under sys preferences -> network. I've been given the workplace IP address which is used for the VPN, and also the IP address of my computer to which I need to remotely access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote Desktop should be enabled on the remote win7 under

> System Properties=>Remote=>Remote Desktop

[image]

The firewall rules will normally automatically be setup for you - if "Remote Desktop" access is enabled.

If it is enabled, then you also need to check if it uses the default port 3389 - if not, you need to check that this port is allowed pass through in the win7 firewall.

Here are some more reading: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404238.aspx

Comment: I've tried with MS Remote Desktop, it gives me a 501 method not implemented error. Is this the reason why?

Comment: 501 should only pop up using a web browser ?? It has something to do with the action used - e.g. is it a GET, POST, CONNECT etc.

Comment: The system admin added me to the VPN list, but I wasn't told anything about enabling remote access on my work PC. Is that a given?

Comment: By default (on a new installation) Remote Desktop access is disabled - I can't comment on how your win7 is set up :)

Comment: If you could help me further: In the gateway configuration, should I include the workplace IP address (which is the same as the VPNs)? I've done so and receive an unauthorised message

Comment: You shouldn't have to change the gateway setup - only the port used for Remote Desktop should be given pass through rights. The VPN is this a setup on your Win7 PC ?? - I don't think it is - The VPN IP-adr. is for the VPN server - after you have gotten the access, you should be able to connect to your work PC, with its LAN IP-adr. (or host name), and a user on this Win7 PC.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've used [**LogMeIn**](https://secure.logmein.com) to remotely connect to a Windows 7 system from my Mac. [**It's perfectly compatible**](http://roaringapps.com/app/logmein-remote-control) with OSX Mavericks, reputable, and secure. I highly recommend it.

Comment: This would require downloading the application on my work PC as well, which I can't do right now. I'm looking for a quick solution. Will try this out sometime

Comment: Any legitimate remote connection from place A requires some sort of preliminary set-up and authentication on place B's end. See my comment above regarding Microsoft Remote desktop. The issue may not be with OSX compatibility, but rather setting up your work PC to remotely log in, regardless of the program.

Answer (score -1):

2x client

its a bit more difficult to setup if you don't know what you are doing.  but I have gotten it to work with one of my clients.  about to try it again with another.